# Is there a function that returns the count of differences between two strings?

Tags: string, count, compare, rust

I'm about to compare to string of equal length. Then I need to count the differences they have. I would start doing that by hand - but since there is such a toolbox of methods I wonder if there is a function that may count the differences that occured anyhow? Or create a collection which I can count the elements in?

Comment: Are you looking for edit distance? There are a smattering of crates that provide routines to compute that, typically using the Levenshtein algorithm.

Comment: nope, you can/need to write one yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementation of Hamming distance is trivial:

```
str_a.chars().zip(str_b.chars()).filter(|x| x.0!=x.1).count()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`strsim`](https://crates.io/crates/strsim) crate. It offers various string difference methods like Hamming, Levenshtein, Damerau-Levenshtein, Jaro, and Jaro-Winkler. I personally like the Damerau-Levenshtein difference, which counts the number of adjacent characters you need to swap and the number of characters you need to remove, insert or replace to turn one of the strings into the other.

```
extern crate strsim;
let difference = strsim::damerau_levenshtein(a, b);
```

Comment: ha hamming would be exactly the thing I have to do - but using a crate for solve this exercise would be kinda cheaty. But I'll take a look at their solution. Mybe I can find the function/method I'm looking for. thx